# Having problems creating main method

Tags: java

Im having trouble creating a main method that can correctly demonstrate this class.  The constructor's arguments have to be in the form MMYYYY. The constructor should read the contents of both files for June 2013(highs062013.txt and lows062013.txt) and store the values in two integer arrays.  The files contain the same amount of data. There is also methods for getting the highest and lowest temp, and the high average and low average.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Weather
{
public Weather(int date) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String dateLow = ("lows" + date + ".txt");
    String dateHigh = ("highs" + date + ".txt");
    File low = new File(dateLow);
    File high = new File(dateHigh);
    FileReader frLow=new FileReader(dateLow);
    FileReader frHigh = new FileReader(dateHigh);
    char[] cLow = new char[(int)dateLow.length()];
    char[] cHigh = new char[(int)dateHigh.length()];
    frLow.read(cLow);
    frHigh.read(cHigh);
}
public char lowest(char[] cLow)
{
    char small = cLow[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < cLow.length; i++)
    {
        if (cLow[i] < small)
        {
            small = cLow[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(small + " is the lowest temp.");
    return small;
}
public char highest(char[] cHigh)
{
    char high = cHigh[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < cHigh.length; i++)
    {
        if (cHigh[i] > high)
        {
            high = cHigh[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(high + " is the highest temp.");
    return high;
}
public int averageLow(char[] cLow)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int averageLow;
    for(int i=0; i < cLow.length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + cLow[i];
    }
    averageLow = sum/cLow.length;
    return averageLow;
    System.out.println(averageLow + " is the average low temp.");
}
public int averageHigh(char[] cHigh)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int averageHigh;
    for(int i=0; i < cHigh.length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + cHigh[i];
    }
    averageHigh = sum/cHigh.length;
    System.out.println(averageHigh + " is the average high temp.");
    return averageHigh;
}
}
```

I need to create a driver method that can demonstrate my code, that Is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: to do what in your code/

Comment: You should specify what kind of problems you have, ideally accompanied by the code you already have, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: the last `system.out` in `averageLow`  will never get reached as you are returning before it is called...

Comment: The issue im having is when calling the methods in the main, How do i get it to recognize the arrays that were created in this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question in your comment, there are two things that you can do:

1.Call the methods at the end of your constructor. When the methods are called, the program statements contained in them will execute.

```
public Weather(int date) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    // code here
    lowest(/*char array variable goes here*/);
    highest(/*char array variable goes here*/);
    // etc.
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Weather(/*int value goes here*/);
}
```

2.Make your variables global so that they can be accessed by all methods in the class.

```
public class Weather
{
    private char[] cLow;
    private char[] cHigh;

    public Weather(int date) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        // code here
        cLow = new char[(int)dateLow.length()];
        cHigh = new char[(int)dateHigh.length()];
        // code here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Weather weather = new Weather(/*int value goes here*/);
        weather.lowest(/*char array variable goes here*/);
        weather.highest(/*char array variable goes here*/);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a main method that corresponds to the correct signature and instantiates your class.  So something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Weather weather = new Weather(<the date you want goes here);
}
```

Comment: I have that, should of added that. Then I do weather.(methodHere) but I dont know how to get the values from the class to carry over to this main method.